# Managing a 2 way relationship in CakePHP without retrieving data twice

Tags: php, cakephp, web-applications

I am having troubling linking some of my models together. Users have one of three roles:

- Student
- Lecturer
- Admin

Information that is shared between the 3 roles is stored in a User table. When a User wants to change their role they make a role request that must be accepted by Admin.

- User has one Student
- User has one Lecturer
- User has one Admin
- User has one RoleRequest
- Student belongs to User
- Lecturer belongs to User
- Admin belongs to User

What I am struggling with is that I cannot find a way of retrieving the data of a user without retrieving their role or their user data twice. If I retrieve the User object with recursive set to 2 I get the user data twice as it is also inside the Lecturer object. If I do the same with the Lecturer object I get the lecturer data twice as it is also inside the User object.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use recursive.  Set `public $recursive=-1;` in your AppModel, then use [CakePHP's AMAZING ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) to retrieve whatever data you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I'm guessing you're not using [Contaible](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

With that behaviour, you can do something like

```
$this->User->find('all', array('contain'=>'Lecturer'));
```

and that will retrieve an array similar to

```
[User] => array(/*user data*/),
[Lecturer] => array(/*Lecturer data*/)
```

Just remember to define your models as containable.